# Задача с модулем random в Python

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Не получается сделать генератор случайных чисел, в котором две цифры будут теми, которые я указал.
Мне нужно, чтобы программа вывела 4 варианта ответов (например: 650, 605, 560 и 506), а пользователь выбрал верный вариант (605). Если вариант пользователя верен, то всё хорошо, если нет, то я напишу другой вариант кода. Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу вывести эти 4 варианта ответов и сравнить их с нужным мне вариантом (который заранее был выбран программой (605).

```
x=6
y=5
z=0
number=     #тут уже должно получаться 4 варианта из порядка первых 3 переменных. Я перепробовал разные варианты, но не выходит то, что мне нужно)
```

Одним предложением можно сказать, что я хочу написать программу, как (Укажите число, в котором 6 единиц и 5 сотен. Варианты ответа: 650, 605, 560, 506)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

x = 6
y = 5
z = 0

# Создаем список из всех возможных комбинаций цифр x, y и z
options = [int(str(x) + str(y) + str(z)), int(str(x) + str(z) + str(y)), int(str(y) + str(x) + str(z)), int(str(z) + str(x) + str(y))]

# Перемешиваем список в случайном порядке
random.shuffle(options)

# Выводим варианты ответов
print("Укажите число, в котором 6 единиц и 5 сотен.")
print("Варианты ответа:")
for i, option in enumerate(options):
    print(f"{i+1}. {option}")

# Записываем правильный ответ (605) в отдельную переменную
correct_answer = 605

# Получаем ответ от пользователя
user_input = int(input("Выберите верный вариант: "))

# Проверяем ответ пользователя
if user_input == correct_answer:
    print("Верно!")
else:
    print("Неверно. Попробуйте еще раз.")
```

Comment: `в котором 6 единиц и 5 сотен`... `правильный ответ (605) `   хм...

Comment: `options = [int(str(x) + str(y) + str(z)), ...]` - это конечно жесть. Во-первых, есть более простой способ объединить три цифры в число, чем несколько раз перегонять строки в числа и обратно, простая арифметика: `100 * x + 10 * y + z`. Во-вторых, хардкодить все возможные комбинации - так себе идея. А если цифр не три будет а 4, тоже так же хардкодить?

Answer (score 5):

```
import itertools
x = 6
y = 5
z = 0
# создадим множество
number = set()
# перебираем различные вариации с помощью itertools.permutations, можете прочитать про него
for i in itertools.permutations(str(x) + str(y) + str(z)):
    # переводим кортежи в строку
    a = ''.join(i)
    # число не может начинаться с нуля
    if a[0] != '0':
        # добавляем в наше множество
        number.add(int(a))
print(number)
```

Я предлагаю использовать `set()`, для того чтобы, например, комбинация `x=4 y=4 z=5` не давала одинаковых значений, если это не нужно, то используйте обычный список `number = []`

Comment: вот тут можно прочитать про itertools https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-itertools.html

Comment: `set` - не "список с уникальными значениями" 

Comment: @wchistow, вы правы, поправил